# MDT reboots after typing password in

Tags: windows, wds, mdt

So, something really weird's going on with MDT.

On this one computer that I'm trying to re-image, it has exhibited multiple weird behaviours, like, initially, it took me to the password screen, I entered my credentials, and after that, it just rebooted.

During other attempts, it either reboots right after it loads the last file or after it gets to the MDT background, or at various other random bits during the process. I think I managed to only get it as far as the credential prompt once, but not past that at all.

Since this is so completely random I thought of posting an other question as other ones I've found online don't match my setup.

WDS runs on a 2008 R2 (don't ask why), and, I did manage to do an F8 after getting into MDT once on the affected machine, and, an ipconfig showed that everything was fine, as, initially, I thought that this was a network driver issue.

Since it doesn't seem to be, I'm completely stumped, as, we've rebuilt dozens of other PCs about a month ago and everything was fine. Those were re-imaged over UEFI PXE boot though, but, for this machine, that doesn't seem to work at all so I have to use the non-uefi PXE boot.

Any thoughts?

(the WDS MDT image is windows 10 64 bit)

Comment: Why do you think this is an MDT issue? Clearly the system has other problems.

Comment: @appleoddity No it doesn't, the only problem is when I try to boot into MDT. UEFI boot works up to a point, but, reboots as well. (everything moves along way too fast anyways) I've seen MDT reboot due to missing network drivers before. Otherwise, it runs the 32 bit 1903 Windows 10 it has on just fine. It is an i7 after all, but, obviously, it's a different model to all the other tablets that were all of the same model.